# "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." pushing history in browser js

Tags: javascript, security

When I push history to browser in the next way:

```
window.history.pushState(
          {
            some_safe_data: data
          },
          'some secure title',
          '//' + translation + '/' + book + '/' + chapter + '/'
        )
```

It say me `SecurityError: The operation is insecure`. The problem is in '//'. When I try to push the url with one slash -- It works. When I add a new one -- it gives me an error.

Why two slashes is not secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use single '/' you append to the current domain, when you use double '/' you are replacing current domain name with 'translation' and that is not allowed because of the same origin policy.

> The new URL can be any URL in the same origin as the current URL. In contrast, setting window.location keeps you at the same document only if you modify only the hash.

[pushState mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Comment: So I need to add origin? => window.location.origin + '//' ...

Comment: No, when you use '//' you need to add domain component to the string, like '//example.com/' + translation + '/' + book + '/' + chapter + '/', but that domain must be of the same origin as the page you are on when executing script.

Comment: FWIW: `//translation/..` represents a [protocol-relative URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Protocol-relative_URLs).